# Why does the Room DB not keep the latest changes?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-room

Before jumping to my Room issue, let me give you an overview. In my app I use the following way to deal with fragments. I have an abstract `BaseFragment` to keep global variables and also, it acts as a base content layout to which are attached another Fragments:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : MainFragment() {

    // Some vars available for classes extended by BaseFragment 

    private val binding get() = _base!!
    private var _base: FragmentBaseBinding? = null


    lateinit var utils: Utils
    ...
    
    val share: Share by activityViewModels()

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _base = null
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
        utils = Utils(requireContext())
        database = ViewModelProvider(this)[DatabaseModel::class.java]
    }
  
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _base = FragmentBaseBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        onCreateBase(inflater, binding.baseFl, savedInstanceState)
        return binding.root
    }

    protected abstract fun onCreateBase(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    )
}
```

Its `fragment_base.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.BaseFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        
        // Custom toolbar

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/base_fl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The rest fragments are extended by `BaseFragment` like this one:

```
class EditFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private val binding get() = edit!!
    private var edit: FragmentEditBinding? = null

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        edit = null
    }

    override fun onCreateBase(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        edit = FragmentEditBinding.inflate(inflater, container, true)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        share.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { 
            // Observed data
        }
        
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Here is the issue. I share some data to the `EditFragment` from a `HomeFragment` using a `ViewModel` class:

```
class Share : ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        data class Data(val id: Long, val mode: String, val page: Int)
    }

    private var _data = MutableLiveData<Data>()
    val data: LiveData<Data> = _data

    fun setData(id: Long, mode: String, page: Int) {
        _data.value = Data(id, mode, page)
    }
}
```

So far everything work good until it comes to change/update some values in Room:

```
...
database.updateById( /* Shared Id */, /* Some updated data */)
// database inited in BaseFragment
...
```

Once I change some values in Room, the changes are kept until I leave the Fragment, which means, the Room accepts new values, but after leaving it restores the previous values that were before changing.

Why could the problem for such a unusual behaviour of Room?

My next question is, whether the way of using one single `BaseFragment`, which gets the rest fragments attached to, makes sense? My thoughts are, it might be an optimized way to use global variables, that you do not need to init for each fragment since they are inited once in `BaseFragment`.

Comment: Why do you have `Data` in companion object? Where are you calling `setData`?

Comment: @TheLibrarian thanks for reply. I think it does not make sense, where I do deslare `Data`, dose it? `setData` i use in `HomeFragment` to share data between with `EditFragment` while navigating to.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't really matter. I understand that you use it in Fragments but the whole point is to figure out why your data is not updated as you want and since you are updating it in some lifecycle event of fragment and not directly as Room should be used, without knowing where you call it from there is no answer.